# Why there is no charge within the conductor even if the charges are static?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, electric-fields, charge, conductors

> "When excess charge is placed on a solid conductor and is at rest, it resides entirely on the surface, not in the interior of the material. �" 
>   Source: 
>   University physics 13th edition p(736).

Regarding the calculation of the electric field due to a uniform charge distribution within a conductor using GAUSS'S law, it's said that  all charges are on the surface of the conductor (nothing within), which I don't understand. Why there is no charge within the conductor even if the charges are static?

Answer (score 3):

> Why there is no charge within the conductor even if the charges are static!?

Informally: If there was *free* charge inside the (perfect) conductor, then there'd be field lines terminating on that charge, exerting a force on it.  But that charge is free to move (it's in a *conductor*) so it would, until the conductor reached a case with zero electric field (hence no free charges) inside it.

(N.B.:  One can try to think of i.e. perfectly symmetric cases where the charge wouldn't have a direction to move; a point charge at the exact center of a sphere for example.  But those are unstable equilibria, and won't last long enough to be significant.)